# Density plot with marginal boxplot

Tags: r, ggpubr

I'm looking for a way to plot the density and boxplot of a feature to compare two groups. I tried using `ggboxplot` and `ggdensity` to get both plots, however, when I wasn't able to find a way to combine them in a way that their axis are adjusted with each other (using `cowplot::plot_grid` or `ggpubr::ggarrange`).

The `ggscatterhist` is pretty much what I'm looking for. I can choose the margin plot, but I couldn't find a way to change the main scatter plot to a boxplot or density. Am I missing something?

Comment: try `patchwork`

Comment: @r2evans I looked into `patchwork` but it doesn't seem to have a share axis parameter. Do you have a specific parameter in mind to align both axis?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: One of the tenet capabilities of `patchwork` is its ability to align axes. Granted, you will be seeing both axes, not "combining" them into one. Since you're talking about marginal plots, have you looked into [`ggExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/index.html)`?

Comment: I just found `ggExtra` and was reading about it (somehow Dean Attali is always the answer). But maybe I should look into `patchwork` some more. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans `patchwork` worked like a charm!! It aligns the axis by default (and not the plot area)! I hadn't realized in the documentation/examples.